# Format a date like "20110822" in Google Open Refine (or Excel)?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, openrefine

I have a dataset that has two different date formats in the same column.  Some are formatted like:

```
2008-05-15T00:00:00Z
```

and others are formatted like:

```
20090804
```

Google Open Refine will recognize the first type as a date and will sort and allow me to perform other operations on it.  I can't figure out how to format the second type into a date.  A transformation of:

```
value.toDate()
```

throws an error, as does most everything else I try.  This seems like a simple problem but Googling is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps (might not!) but with `20090804` in A1:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

should return a value formatted as a recognisable date.

Might be wrapped in a condition like so:

```
=IF(LEN(A1=8),DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),A1)
```

such that either the first format is returned or the alternative version, according to requirement.